# reading from a file and filling a link list android

Tags: android

i'm trying to read from a text file and put each line in a node 
the file looks like this : 
2000;aston martin;Aston Martin;DB9;Car;A 
2001;aston martin;Aston Martin;DB9;Car;B 
2002;aston martin;Aston Martin;V8 VANTAGE;Car;C
 
2003;aston martin;Aston Martin;V8 VANTAGE;Car;D

i want to separate the line with " ; " and put every String in a value in the node

BUT THE LINK IS STILL EMPTY

although in JAVA simple program this code of link list acts well
but there's a proplem in reading

Pleaaaase help

THIS IS THE CODE :

```
class node{
    node next ; 
    node previous ;
    String year ;
    String company ;
    String manufacture ;
    String modelname;
    String type ;
    String owner;
 }
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        node head = null ;
        node tail = new node ();
        node nn= null;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[]tokens = new String [5] ;

        try{

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("config.txt");
        // Get the object of DataInputStream
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line="";
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            tokens = line.split(";");

            if (head==null){
                head = new node ();
                head.year=tokens[0];
                head.company =tokens[1];
                head.manufacture=tokens[2];
                head.modelname =tokens[3];
                head.type= tokens[4];
                head.owner=tokens[5];
                head.next = null;
                head.previous=null;
                tail=head;
            }
        else { 
        nn = new node ();
        nn.year=tokens[0];
        nn.company =tokens[1];
        nn.manufacture=tokens[2];
        nn.modelname =tokens[3];
        nn.type= tokens[4];
        nn.owner=tokens[5];
        tail.next = nn ;
        nn.previous = tail ;
        tail=nn;
        nn.next = null;
        }

        }

        in.close();
  }

    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: `BUT THE LINK IS STILL EMPTY` - what link?  I can see you creating some nodes but you don't seem to do anything with them.

Comment: two things, 1- please log `line` to see if it is actually reading lines 2- why are you linking nodes to each other with next and previous? wouldn't be an `ArrayList` more convenient?

Comment: cuz it's an assignment and i have to create a linked list  with next and previous ... and i think the 'line' is still empty too is there a must path to put the text in ?!